# How do I go about installing ColdFusion 11 Trial on an Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: coldfusion, ubuntu-14.04

I want to try changing my development environment from Windows 8 to Ubuntu so I would like to know if it is possible to install CF11 Trial on an Ubuntu? It will be my first time working with Linux. I already know how to install Postgre 9.3 and pgAdmin. I'm clueless with CF though. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.04 and 13.10 are supported with ColdFusion 11. Here is the list of [supported environments](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/coldfusion/pdfs/cf11/coldfusion11-support-matrix.pdf). You can [download CF11 here](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=coldfusion). For installation instructions, see:  [Installing the Server Configuration](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Installing+the+Server+Configuration)

Comment: You can try installing it, but officially, its not supported.